# Is there a unique homomorphism from a ring to its field of fractions?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

We have a canonical homomorphism from a ring $R$ to its field of fractions $Q(R)$ given by $f : r\mapsto r/1$.

Is this homomorphism unique?

So letting $g: R\rightarrow Q(R)$ be a homomorphism, by the universal property of the field of fractions, there exists a unique homomorphism $h:Q(R)\rightarrow Q(R)$ such that $g = h\circ f$. By this universal property it follows that it should be enough to prove that $h$ is the identity map, but I am not sure if this has to be the case.

---

**Added part:** As follows from the answers/discussion below, in general the above is not true. Now I wonder, is it true when $R$ is a discrete valuation ring?

Comment: When you ask if the homomorphism $f:R\to Q(R)$ is unique, are you asking if $f$ is the only ring homomorphism $R\to Q(R)$? Or are you asking if $f$ is the only ring homomorphism $R\to Q(R)$ that satisfies the universal property that $f$ satisfies?

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard The first question. I read somewhere that when R is a discrete valuation ring and Q(R) its field of fractions, then there is a unique homomorphism from R to Q(R). I wondered why this would be true. Maybe being a DVR adds something extra such that it will be true, but I don’t see it.

Comment: I think that rather than add questions to a question that has already been answered, it is better to post a new question. Not all the people who've answered your original question may be aware that you've added to it, and that their answers are no longer complete.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard I was curious myself, so I’ve posted a follow-up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3573818/274352).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be more than one ring homomorphism $R\to Q(R)$. Let's look at an example to see why:

Let $R$ be the polynomial ring $\Bbb{C}[t]$. So $Q(R)=\Bbb{C}(t)$. If we pick any element $r\in\Bbb{C}(t)$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\phi_r:\Bbb{C}[t]\to\Bbb{C}(t)$ with $\phi_r(t)=r$ and $\phi_r(z)=z$ for all $z\in\Bbb{C}$. Note: $\phi_r$ is the map which sends $p(t)\mapsto p(r)$ for each polynomial $p(t)\in\Bbb{C}[t]$. So if $R=\Bbb{C}[t]$, then there are lots of ring homomorphisms $R\to Q(R)$.

Answer (score 5):

No, it need not be unique in general. To see why, consider the chain of maps

$$R\xrightarrow{g} R\xrightarrow{f} Q(R)\xrightarrow{h}Q(R).$$

We can “toggle” what $g$ and $h$ are to get different maps from $R$ to $Q(R)$. Since $R$ and $Q(R)$ might have nontrivial endomorphisms, your canonical morphism won’t always be unique.

I wonder when it *is* unique, though. Certainly $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ is unique, but I’m not sure about other rings...

Comment: regarding your last comment, that is probably a bad example since $$ \mathbb Z \to A$$ is unique for any ring. I think I'm honeslty hard pressed for any other example that is not of this type