# When is the natural inclusion of an integral domain into its field of fractions unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

*This is a follow up question stemming from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3571981/274352) prior MSE post.*

Given an integral domain $R$, there is a natural inclusion of $R$ into its ring of fractions $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$. Under what conditions is this the *only* ring homomorphism $R\to \operatorname{Frac}(R)$? In particular, does it suffice for $R$ to be a DVR?

(Note that a necessary condition for this to hold is for $R$ and $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ to have trivial endomorphism groups.)

I see two examples. When $R = \mathbb{Z}$ this is true because $\mathbb{Z}$ is initial in the category of rings. When $R = \mathbb{Z}_p$, this feels like it ought to be true since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has no nontrivial ring endomorphisms.

Comment: Nitpick: when you say "ring", you obviously mean "integral domain". Otherwise, how is the ring of fractions defined?

Comment: @WillR Oh, yes absolutely. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it will suffice for $R$ to be a DVR, because you can take a nontrivial finite unramified extension $K/\Bbb Q_p$ and then restriction of a nontrivial element of $G(K/\Bbb Q_p)$ should give you a nontrivial automorphism of $\mathcal O_K$ (how obvious this is I guess depends on whether you're familiar with the correspondence between unramified extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$ and finite extensions of $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: I would think the answer is "virtually never", since the necessary condition that $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ has no nontrivial endomorphisms is already quite rare.  (In particular there are easy examples of DVRs where it fails, for instance $k[[x]]$ for any field $k$ with a nontrivial endomorphism.)

Comment: (Also, any nontrivial endomorphism of $R$ induces a nontrivial endomorphism of $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ so you might as well just think about endomorphisms of $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$.)